# how to plot an histogram with uneven bins in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, bar-chart, histogram

for this code, I see this histogram

'''

```
t = unique_seq_Dataframe.groupby(by="frequency").count()
unique_seq_Dataframe.frequency.hist(bins=range(0,50,2))
```

'''
[image]

and for this code, I see this histogram

```
unique_seq_Dataframe.frequency.hist(bins=10)
```

[image]

I want to see the distribution that is demonstrated in the first plot but I would like to preserve the bars that are seen in the second plot of the 3081 and 4845 without losing the resolution of the first plot. (note that the values are distributed between 1-50, and both of the bars of 3081 and 4845)

see data below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

By definition of a histogram, you cannot maintain the resolution of the lower binned values while preserving the higher values. Binning groups data points to their nearest bin in order to show you what are relevant features. If you consider your high values to not be outliers then the differences between the low values approach 0. That is to say the difference between 10 and 5 can be thought of as 0 when compared to the difference between 3000 and 10.

However, if you consider 3000 to be an outlier, the difference between 3000 and 10 is artificially so large that it is not relevant, and thus it gets grouped into the bin at 50. The difference between 10 and 5 is relevant and thus you get the resolution you desire.

Your histograms show that the largest two data points are outliers. If you do not want to consider them outliers then the low values are basically all equivalent and can be assumed to be 0. Thus, you get three bars in the second graph.

I will add that simply extending the y-axis and the number of bins by:

```
unique_seq_Dataframe.frequency.hist(bins=range(0,5000,2))
```

may give you the graph you want but carries no histogram information. Having this many bins to include outliers reduces your histogram to a scatter plot where individual points are just purely plotted.